# Display result without loading/refreshing the page using php,mysql,html,javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I'm using php(**insert.php**) to store/insert data in mysql.

I'm also using another php file(**display.php**) to display the result.

I'd like to ask , every time when I insert, how can show the inserted data of **insert.php** to **display.php** without loading/ refreshing **display.php** immediately.

Thanks.

Comment: you should use AJAX then   make http request to display.php then get write result into html element

Comment: search for xmlhttprequest

Answer (score 1):

Use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) or [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). On **display.php** in `setInverval()` once in few milliseconds send a request to the server. Also you can realize *long polling* via AJAX or Fetch API.